# File close error, [AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'close'] when reducing file write code to a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

Going through Zed Shaw's book Exercise 17 [about copying one file to another] where he reduces his these two lines of code

```
in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()
```

into one as :

```
indata = open(from_file).read()
```

there's also a piece of code where he writes

```
out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)
```

So I was reducing this into one line same as above :

```
out_file = open(to_file, 'w').write(indata)
```

This seems to work fine but when I close the `out_file` there's an error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filesCopy.py", line 27, in <module>
    out_file.close()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'close'
```

I am unable to grasp what is going on and how `close()` is working here?

Comment: `.write(..)` does *not* return a fil handler, but an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two are **not** equivalent. If you write `out_file = open(to_file, 'w').write(indata)`, you have implicitly written:

```
# equivalent to second code sample
temp = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file = temp.write(indata)
```

Now as we can see in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) of `write()`:

> `f.write(string)` writes the contents of string to the file, **returning the number of characters written**.

So it returns an integer. So in your second sample `out_file` is *not* a file handler, but an integer. Further in the code, you somewhere aim to close the `out_file` file handler with `out_file.close()`. But since `out_file` is no longer a file handler, it thus makes no sense to call close on this.

Nevertheless, by using a context, you do no longer need to perform a `.close()` yourself, so more elegantly is probably:

```
with open(to_file, 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(indata)
```

The reduction in the book itself is allowed (well at least semantically, it is better to use context manager), since the author probably never closes the file handle explicitly.

Comment: This sums it up. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 2):

The `write` method **returns the number of characters written in your file** which is an integer not a file object and therefore doesn't have a `close` method.

```
In [6]: a = open('test', 'w')          
In [7]: t = a.write('ssss')
In [8]: t
Out[8]: 4
```

Also, calling the I/O methods directly on `open()` is recommended only if you don't want to have any further interaction with the file. Besides, the most proper way to deal with file objects is to use a `with` statement that closes the file automatically at the end of the block and there's no need to call the `close()` manually.

```
with open('filename', 'w') as f:
    # do something
```

Comment: But explicitly writing: 

`out_file = open(to_file, 'w')`
`out_file.write(indata)`

`out_file.close()`

works. Why ?

Comment: @f__society Because that's the way it should be. The fact that you can close your file manually is a great feature that can be used when you want to keep your file object for a longer time and use it in multiple places (withing a module) and/or within other objects. In that case you won't loose the reference after doing some operations. like what happens in `with` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Following is usually better approach, both for reading & writing:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as f:
    # do something with f
```

There is no need to close f with this code.

With code `val = open(to_file, 'w').write(indata)` "val" will be return value of `write` function, not `open` function.

Comment: So is there some precedence involved in these functions? Like in your example `val` is assigned return value of `write()` and not `open()`

Comment: It will be the return value of last performed function.

Answer (score 1):

The `read()` function reads the file and then returns the file content, so when you assign `indata` to `read()` it's assigning the returned file content.  The difference is that the `write()` function returns the number of characters written, therefore your `outdata` is now an `int` object.

Read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Therefore, you cannot combine the `write()` function into one line and expect to have a referenced file object to close after, and that's disastrous.

The preferred way is to use the `with` block.  Refer to @Willem's answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The author "Zed" has already clarified when you will read the page 64 from that book. Please read below:

> **When I try to make this script shorter, I get an error when I close the files at the end.** 
>   You probably did something like this, indata = open(from_file).read(), which means you don’t need to then do in_file.close() when you reach the end of the script. It should already be closed by Python once that one line runs.